# InvalidProgramException - Stacktrace

Tags: windows-phone-7, stack-trace, utc

I have received the following stacktrace. But I cannot figure out which function from which class has raised this. Can anyone tell me what MainPage..ctor is??

> "Frame    Image             Function                      Offset
>
> 0        coredll.dll       xxx_RaiseException                     19
>
> 1        mscoree3_7.dll                                       520892
>
> 2        mscoree3_7.dll                                           461967
>
> 3        mscoree3_7.dll                                           534468
>
> 4                          TransitionStub                              0
>
> 5           System.InternalTimeZoneInfo.TransitionTimeToDateTime       520
>
> 6           System.InternalTimeZoneInfo.GetDaylightTime           100
>
> 7           System.InternalTimeZoneInfo.GetIsDaylightSavingsFromUtc    128
>
> 8           System.InternalTimeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffsetFromUtc       500
>
> 9                          System.DateTime.ToLocalTime                164
>
> 10                         System.DateTime.get_Now                72
>
> 11                         System.DateTime.get_Today          44
>
> 12                         xxxx.MainPage..ctor                    84
>
> 13       mscoree3_7.dll                                           507848
>
> 14       mscoree3_7.dll                                       184683
>
> 15       mscoree3_7.dll                                           183987
>
> 16       mscoree3_7.dll                                           183375
>
> 17         System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke        104
>
> 18         System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.InternalInvoke        1056
>
> 19            System.Activator.InternalCreateInstance             1112"

This is the mainpage constructor:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeButtons();
    CreateCalendar();
    DisplayHistory();
    DisplayStatistics();
}
```

And inside `CreateCalendar` I have initialized a variable `DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Today;` Is this the one creating the trouble?

Comment: Hi, could you share some code? for example the one you are running into MainPage constructor? try to put this code in MainPage.Loaded event method instead of inside the contructor...

Comment: MainPage..ctor is constructor??

Comment: yes, "ctor" stands for constructor

Comment: @josemiguel.torres I have edited the post to add the constructor code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to you to move the methods to Page loaded event as follow:

```
public MainPage()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     Loaded += MainPage_Loaded; // you may declare it in xaml as well
}

private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CreateCalendar();
    DisplayHistory();
    DisplayStatistics();
}
```

Depending on the kind of operations you are performing inside each method -mainly if it envolves UI -it would be recommended to wrap it into a Dispatcher:

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CreateCalendar(); //assuming this method does not use UI
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
    {
     //asuming these methods use UI
     DisplayHistory();
     DisplayStatistics();
    });
}
```

Try it out and let us know,,

cheers

Comment: Thank you. I'l try that and post the results.Could you explain why a dispatcher is needed. All the three functions involves both UI as well as other data manipulation operation. Dispatcher can only have the UI operations or both the data as well?

Comment: All the WP7 Controls are drawn by the UI thread. On the other hand, all the calls in WP7 are async so when you perform an operation and the calling thread is different from UI thread it can't perform any UI operation directly. Dispatcher.BeginInvoke queues such call as a work item in the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this error occasionaly came out of the blue with some insignificant changes. It failed in initialization stage of tests under running Silverlight Unit Test Framework. Changes were made in project that was indirectly referenced from Unit Test project (i.e. Unit Test project referenced Windows Phone library and the library referenced PCL with changes).

It's redundant to say thay the code I added didn't execute at all when the crash happened!

After commenting out new code with bisection method I ended up that commenting a single line stopped throwing the exception. The line was like this:

var items = jData["items"].Select(token => token.ToObject()).ToList();

where jData is JObject instance from well-known Json.NET. Updating to recent version of Json.NET didn't help.

The error is gone after replacing LINQ expression with explicit ugly for loop (scoffing Resharper says "for loop can be converted to LINQ expression).

So I'm starting to believe in magic.

Hope this helps someone.